# How to add specific item from list on button click in java ee?

Tags: java, http, servlets, java-ee-7

I recently started learning java ee and i want to make a small shop application.
In the code below i added some articles in list and i can display them on my jsp.

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    ArrayList<Artical> articals = Artical.getArticals();
    request.setAttribute("articals", articals);       
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

Here is where i display articals and where i create a button:

```
 <body>
    <h1>Welcome ${user.name}</h1>
  
    <c:forEach var="artical" items="${articals}">
        <ul>
            <li>${artical.name}
                <form action="addtocart" method="POST">
                    <button type="submit" name="button">Add to cart</button></form></li>
            <li>${artical.price}</li>
        </ul>
    </c:forEach>

</body>
```

I want when i click "Add to cart" button, to add that item to cart(in my case just to display them). So how my "addtocart" servlet should look like? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add hidden field inside your `<form></form>` so that on click of your button form will take your `name` and `price` values of items to servlet where you can add these in your `List`.i.e:

```
<c:forEach var="artical" items="${articals}">
        <ul>
            <li>${artical.name}
                <form action="addtocart" method="POST"> 
                    <!--add below inputs-->
                   <input type="hidden" name="names" value="${artical.name}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="${artical.price}"/>
                    <button type="submit" name="button">Add to cart</button></form></li>
            <li>${artical.price}</li>
        </ul>
    </c:forEach>
```

Then in your servlets `doPost()` method get these values using `request.getParameter("..")` i.e:

```
 String names= request.getParameter("names");
    String price= request.getParameter("price");
 //add in list and then add that list in sessions
```